# How to solve flickering issue for Table with Static header and left columns in IE and Safari | angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Have tried creating a table which has sticky headers and left columns, in chrome on scroll, table seems to look fine without flickering, where as in Internet Explorer and Safari Browser, can see a huge flickering, while scrolling with in the table. Expectation is headers and left columns need to be sticked without any flickering.

This is what tried:

directive:

```
angular.module('app')
    .directive('StickyTable', StickyTable);

  function StickyTable($timeout){
    return{
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        tpl: '@tpl'
      },
      template: '<ng-include src="loadTpl()"></ng-include>',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs){

        scope.loadTpl = function () {
          return scope.tpl;
        };
        $timeout(function(){
          var StickyHeaders = angular.element(elem).find('.sticky-headers'),
            StickyLeftCells = angular.element(elem).find('.sticky-left-cells');
          angular.element(StickyHeaders).bind('scroll', function(event){
            var currentTarget = angular.element(event.currentTarget);
            currentTarget.find('table tr.sticky-row th').css('top', currentTarget.scrollTop());
            currentTarget.find('table tr.sticky-row td').css('top', currentTarget.scrollTop());
          });
          angular.element(StickyLeftCells).bind('scroll', function(event){
            var currentTarget = angular.element(event.currentTarget);
            currentTarget.find('table th.sticky-cell').css('left', currentTarget.scrollLeft());
            currentTarget.find('table td.sticky-cell').css('left', currentTarget.scrollLeft());
          }); 
        });
      }
    };
  }

  StickyTable.$inject = ['$timeout'];
```

index.html:

```
<sticky-table tpl="stickytable.html"></sticky-table>
```

stickytable.html:

```
<div class="sticky-table sticky-headers sticky-left-cells">
  <table id="table1" class="table" ng-controller="stickyTableCtrl">
      <thead>
          <tr class="sticky-row">
              <th class="sticky-cell">ID</th>
              <th class="sticky-cell">Country</th>
              <th class="sticky-cell">State</th>
              <th>City</th>
              <th>Country Code</th>
              <th>IP Address</th>
              <th>Language</th>
              <th>Number</th>
              <th>Postal Code</th>
              <th>Shirt Size</th>
              <th>Color</th>
              <th>Time Zone</th>
              <th>Boolean</th>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Gender</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Race</th>
              <th>Currency</th>
              <th>Currency Code</th>
              <th>Title</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="data in tableData track by $index">
              <td class="sticky-cell">{{data.id}}</td>
              <td class="sticky-cell">{{data.Country}}</td>
              <td class="sticky-cell">{{data.State}}</td>
              <td>{{data.City}}</td>
              <td>{{data.Country_Code}}</td>
              <td>{{data.ip_address}}</td>
              <td>{{data.Language}}</td>
              <td>{{data.Number}}</td>
              <td>{{data.Postal_Code}}</td>
              <td>{{data.Color}}</td>
              <td>{{data.Shirt_Size}}</td>
              <td>{{data.Time_Zone}}</td>
              <td>{{data.Boolean}}</td>
              <td>{{data.Date}}</td>
              <td>{{data.Gender}}</td>
              <td>{{data.Name}}</td>
              <td>{{data.Race}}</td>
              <td>{{data.Currency}}</td>
              <td>{{data.Currency_Code}}</td>
              <td>{{data.Title}}</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('stickyTableCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.tableData = [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "Country": "United States",
              "State": "District of Columbia",
              "City": "Washington",
              "Country_Code": "US",
              "ip_address": "90.5.210.157",
              "Language": "Burmese",
              "Number": 204312,
              "Postal_Code": "20508",
              "Color": "#769",
              "Shirt_Size": "L",
              "Time_Zone": "Asia/Tashkent",
              "Boolean": true,
              "Date": "3/9/1942",
              "Gender": "Female",
              "Name": "Jeffrey Sullivan",
              "Race": "Paiute",
              "Currency": "Dollar",
              "Currency_Code": "USD",
              "Title": "Staff Accountant II"
            },
            {
              "id": 2,
              "Country": "United States",
              "State": "Georgia",
              "City": "Atlanta",
              "Country_Code": "US",
              "ip_address": "130.218.125.142",
              "Language": "Amharic",
              "Number": 575416,
              "Postal_Code": "31165",
              "Color": "#363",
              "Shirt_Size": "M",
              "Time_Zone": "America/Phoenix",
              "Boolean": true,
              "Date": "2/21/1989",
              "Gender": "Male",
              "Name": "Patricia Cox",
              "Race": "Argentinian",
              "Currency": "Dollar",
              "Currency_Code": "USD",
              "Title": "Engineer II"
            },
            {
              "id": 3,
              "Country": "United States",
              "State": "Texas",
              "City": "San Antonio",
              "Country_Code": "US",
              "ip_address": "44.67.50.181",
              "Language": "Hebrew",
              "Number": 472356,
              "Postal_Code": "78205",
              "Color": "#363",
              "Shirt_Size": "XL",
              "Time_Zone": "Asia/Irkutsk",
              "Boolean": false,
              "Date": "6/19/1917",
              "Gender": "Female",
              "Name": "Carolyn Day",
              "Race": "Vietnamese",
              "Currency": "Dollar",
              "Currency_Code": "USD",
              "Title": "Computer Systems Analyst II"
            },
            {
              "id": 4,
              "Country": "United States",
              "State": "Georgia",
              "City": "Augusta",
              "Country_Code": "US",
              "ip_address": "31.237.138.124",
              "Language": "Telugu",
              "Number": 828131,
              "Postal_Code": "30919",
              "Color": "#731",
              "Shirt_Size": "S",
              "Time_Zone": "America/Guatemala",
              "Boolean": true,
              "Date": "5/19/1968",
              "Gender": "Male",
              "Name": "Debra Greene",
              "Race": "Seminole",
              "Currency": "Dollar",
              "Currency_Code": "USD",
              "Title": "Cost Accountant"
            },
            {
              "id": 5,
              "Country": "United States",
              "State": "Arizona",
              "City": "Phoenix",
              "Country_Code": "US",
              "ip_address": "112.214.16.103",
              "Language": "Czech",
              "Number": 424075,
              "Postal_Code": "85083",
              "Color": "#c6b",
              "Shirt_Size": "XL",
              "Time_Zone": "Europe/Madrid",
              "Boolean": false,
              "Date": "5/31/1923",
              "Gender": "Female",
              "Name": "Jeremy Sanders",
              "Race": "Pueblo",
              "Currency": "Dollar",
              "Currency_Code": "USD",
              "Title": "Food Chemist"
            },
            {
              "id": 6,
              "Country": "United States",
              "State": "Pennsylvania",
              "City": "Philadelphia",
              "Country_Code": "US",
              "ip_address": "169.46.177.188",
              "Language": "Indonesian",
              "Number": 434049,
              "Postal_Code": "19141",
              "Color": "#85e",
              "Shirt_Size": "M",
              "Time_Zone": "America/La_Paz",
              "Boolean": false,
              "Date": "9/21/1960",
              "Gender": "Female",
              "Name": "Theresa Reid",
              "Race": "South American",
              "Currency": "Dollar",
              "Currency_Code": "USD",
              "Title": "VP Marketing"
            },
            {
              "id": 7,
              "Country": "United States",
              "State": "Texas",
              "City": "Austin",
              "Country_Code": "US",
              "ip_address": "56.130.162.56",
              "Language": "Swati",
              "Number": 664513,
              "Postal_Code": "78769",
              "Color": "#520",
              "Shirt_Size": "2XL",
              "Time_Zone": "Africa/Casablanca",
              "Boolean": true,
              "Date": "7/31/1917",
              "Gender": "Male",
              "Name": "Heather Ray",
              "Race": "Ecuadorian",
              "Currency": "Dollar",
              "Currency_Code": "USD",
              "Title": "Assistant Media Planner"
            },
            {
              "id": 8,
              "Country": "United States",
              "State": "Washington",
              "City": "Vancouver",
              "Country_Code": "US",
              "ip_address": "102.74.24.28",
              "Language": "Indonesian",
              "Number": 918579,
              "Postal_Code": "98682",
              "Color": "#1b9",
              "Shirt_Size": "XS",
              "Time_Zone": "Pacific/Guam",
              "Boolean": false,
              "Date": "7/17/1997",
              "Gender": "Male",
              "Name": "Virginia Morrison",
              "Race": "Comanche",
              "Currency": "Dollar",
              "Currency_Code": "USD",
              "Title": "Help Desk Operator"
            },
            {
              "id": 9,
              "Country": "United States",
              "State": "New York",
              "City": "Brooklyn",
              "Country_Code": "US",
              "ip_address": "10.171.85.151",
              "Language": "Albanian",
              "Number": 87787,
              "Postal_Code": "11225",
              "Color": "#858",
              "Shirt_Size": "XS",
              "Time_Zone": "Asia/Hong_Kong",
              "Boolean": true,
              "Date": "11/6/2010",
              "Gender": "Male",
              "Name": "Keith Campbell",
              "Race": "Cambodian",
              "Currency": "Dollar",
              "Currency_Code": "USD",
              "Title": "VP Quality Control"
            },
            {
              "id": 10,
              "Country": "United States",
              "State": "Arkansas",
              "City": "North Little Rock",
              "Country_Code": "US",
              "ip_address": "58.224.66.202",
              "Language": "Moldovan",
              "Number": 635459,
              "Postal_Code": "72118",
              "Color": "#e78",
              "Shirt_Size": "S",
              "Time_Zone": "Pacific/Guam",
              "Boolean": true,
              "Date": "3/26/1995",
              "Gender": "Male",
              "Name": "Lisa Nichols",
              "Race": "White",
              "Currency": "Dollar",
              "Currency_Code": "USD",
              "Title": "Legal Assistant"
            },
            {
              "id": 11,
              "Country": "United States",
              "State": "Florida",
              "City": "Miami",
              "Country_Code": "US",
              "ip_address": "82.25.157.89",
              "Language": "Bosnian",
              "Number": 539519,
              "Postal_Code": "33164",
              "Color": "#abb",
              "Shirt_Size": "L",
              "Time_Zone": "Asia/Colombo",
              "Boolean": true,
              "Date": "5/5/1947",
              "Gender": "Female",
              "Name": "Kathryn Gonzales",
              "Race": "Ottawa",
              "Currency": "Dollar",
              "Currency_Code": "USD",
              "Title": "Professor"
            },
            {
              "id": 12,
              "Country": "United States",
              "State": "Massachusetts",
              "City": "Boston",
              "Country_Code": "US",
              "ip_address": "195.51.71.219",
              "Language": "Nepali",
              "Number": 35318,
              "Postal_Code": "02119",
              "Color": "#d61",
              "Shirt_Size": "S",
              "Time_Zone": "Etc/UTC",
              "Boolean": true,
              "Date": "4/12/1959",
              "Gender": "Female",
              "Name": "Janice Mills",
              "Race": "Venezuelan",
              "Currency": "Dollar",
              "Currency_Code": "USD",
              "Title": "Help Desk Technician"
            },
            {
              "id": 13,
              "Country": "United States",
              "State": "Massachusetts",
              "City": "Boston",
              "Country_Code": "US",
              "ip_address": "47.218.126.118",
              "Language": "Thai",
              "Number": 80364,
              "Postal_Code": "02216",
              "Color": "#21e",
              "Shirt_Size": "2XL",
              "Time_Zone": "America/Caracas",
              "Boolean": true,
              "Date": "1/2/1965",
              "Gender": "Female",
              "Name": "Virginia Tucker",
              "Race": "Venezuelan",
              "Currency": "Dollar",
              "Currency_Code": "USD",
              "Title": "Quality Control Specialist"
            },
            {
              "id": 14,
              "Country": "United States",
              "State": "Virginia",
              "City": "Lynchburg",
              "Country_Code": "US",
              "ip_address": "222.120.50.203",
              "Language": "Malayalam",
              "Number": 928058,
              "Postal_Code": "24503",
              "Color": "#ec8",
              "Shirt_Size": "2XL",
              "Time_Zone": "Australia/Melbourne",
              "Boolean": false,
              "Date": "5/28/1999",
              "Gender": "Male",
              "Name": "Harry Foster",
              "Race": "Laotian",
              "Currency": "Dollar",
              "Currency_Code": "USD",
              "Title": "Human Resources Assistant I"
            },
            {
              "id": 15,
              "Country": "United States",
              "State": "Kansas",
              "City": "Shawnee Mission",
              "Country_Code": "US",
              "ip_address": "1.67.94.102",
              "Language": "Hiri Motu",
              "Number": 606906,
              "Postal_Code": "66205",
              "Color": "#b9c",
              "Shirt_Size": "2XL",
              "Time_Zone": "Asia/Bangkok",
              "Boolean": false,
              "Date": "12/2/1947",
              "Gender": "Female",
              "Name": "Joseph Green",
              "Race": "Ute",
              "Currency": "Dollar",
              "Currency_Code": "USD",
              "Title": "General Manager"
            },
            {
              "id": 16,
              "Country": "United States",
              "State": "Texas",
              "City": "Lubbock",
              "Country_Code": "US",
              "ip_address": "18.35.196.98",
              "Language": "Tetum",
              "Number": 365862,
              "Postal_Code": "79452",
              "Color": "#828",
              "Shirt_Size": "L",
              "Time_Zone": "Pacific/Majuro",
              "Boolean": true,
              "Date": "6/10/1924",
              "Gender": "Female",
              "Name": "Earl Sanders",
              "Race": "Uruguayan",
              "Currency": "Dollar",
              "Currency_Code": "USD",
              "Title": "Assistant Manager"
            },
            {
              "id": 17,
              "Country": "United States",
              "State": "North Carolina",
              "City": "Raleigh",
              "Country_Code": "US",
              "ip_address": "224.63.145.101",
              "Language": "Guaraní",
              "Number": 940057,
              "Postal_Code": "27690",
              "Color": "#78f",
              "Shirt_Size": "3XL",
              "Time_Zone": "Australia/Sydney",
              "Boolean": false,
              "Date": "9/22/1971",
              "Gender": "Female",
              "Name": "Maria Smith",
              "Race": "Tlingit-Haida",
              "Currency": "Dollar",
              "Currency_Code": "USD",
              "Title": "Chief Design Engineer"
            },
            {
              "id": 18,
              "Country": "United States",
              "State": "New York",
              "City": "Rochester",
              "Country_Code": "US",
              "ip_address": "204.212.79.154",
              "Language": "Maltese",
              "Number": 885563,
              "Postal_Code": "14646",
              "Color": "#e08",
              "Shirt_Size": "3XL",
              "Time_Zone": "Europe/Minsk",
              "Boolean": true,
              "Date": "8/22/1978",
              "Gender": "Female",
              "Name": "Henry Castillo",
              "Race": "Spaniard",
              "Currency": "Dollar",
              "Currency_Code": "USD",
              "Title": "Community Outreach Specialist"
            },
            {
              "id": 19,
              "Country": "United States",
              "State": "North Dakota",
              "City": "Fargo",
              "Country_Code": "US",
              "ip_address": "187.9.143.245",
              "Language": "Romanian",
              "Number": 874313,
              "Postal_Code": "58106",
              "Color": "#d8a",
              "Shirt_Size": "3XL",
              "Time_Zone": "Asia/Tokyo",
              "Boolean": true,
              "Date": "4/24/1975",
              "Gender": "Female",
              "Name": "Craig Long",
              "Race": "Kiowa",
              "Currency": "Dollar",
              "Currency_Code": "USD",
              "Title": "Software Consultant"
            },
            {
              "id": 20,
              "Country": "United States",
              "State": "California",
              "City": "Orange",
              "Country_Code": "US",
              "ip_address": "91.209.80.130",
              "Language": "Polish",
              "Number": 265117,
              "Postal_Code": "92668",
              "Color": "#40c",
              "Shirt_Size": "2XL",
              "Time_Zone": "Pacific/Port_Moresby",
              "Boolean": true,
              "Date": "4/17/1991",
              "Gender": "Male",
              "Name": "Martha Schmidt",
              "Race": "Eskimo",
              "Currency": "Dollar",
              "Currency_Code": "USD",
              "Title": "Business Systems Development Analyst"
            }
          ];
    }]);
```

Sass:

```
.sticky-table {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 80vh;
  overflow: auto;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 0 !important;
  table {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
    padding: 0 !important;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    tr.sticky-row {
      th, td {
        background-color: #fff;
        border-top: 0;
        position: relative;
        outline: 1px solid #ddd;
        z-index: 5;
      }
    }
    td.sticky-cell, th.sticky-cell {
      background-color: #fff;
      outline: 1px solid #ddd;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 10;
    }
    tr.sticky-row {
      td.sticky-cell, th.sticky-cell {
        z-index: 15;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you use the StickyTable directive?

Comment: in index html, placed the reference in this question.